# Can not access Google App Engine Dashboard / unable to deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, dashboard

I recently created a new google account and registered a new domain for google app engine that i want to use now with a java gae project i wrote.

When i try to access

https://appengine.google.com/

or

https://appengine.google.com/a/my-domain.com

i always get redirected to a page

> "Welcome to Google App Engine Before getting started, you want to
>   learn more about developing and deploying applications."..... Create
>   Application

When i push this button, and enter the phone number i used to create the account/domain this is refused with:

> The phone number has been sent too many messages or has already been
>   used to confirm an account.

I am not able to deploy my GAE application as i simply dont know the Application ID. I can not create a new one and i can not find out if i already created one as there is no way to access the dashboard.

Any Hint?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already used that number to validate a different Google account, you need to create the application with that account.

More information at the [SMS Verification for App Creation FAQ](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/sms)

Comment: I only used the number for this account. I have not created a different one in years.

Comment: @REDSOFTADAIR Well, [computer says no](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOdjCb4LwQY) try to open an [issue in the production](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue)

Comment: Indeed you were right. I confirmed the new account with a old existing google account and i had to confirm this one with the sms. All this is quite confusing. Problem solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google recommends to fill out the following form in this event to verify the account manually:
https://appengine.google.com/waitlist/sms_issues